# Could not find any available simulators for iOS when carthage build --no-skip-current --cache-builds --platform iOS

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

I am getting the following error:

> Could not find any available simulators for iOS while generating the framework carthage build --no-skip-current --cache-builds --platform iOS

I am using Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Try running `xcrun simctl list` in Terminal to see if you have any simulators.

Comment: i run  xcrun simctl list devices --json
Got the below response


  "devices" : {
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "790ED014-E29E-4E33-BE71-46BDF1D36E68",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      }

Comment: Then try `Add additional simulators`/`Download simulators`. It seems Carthage can't find the simulator because you don't have one.